# How to avoide too many dependencies when flow use many call to external vendor

Tags: dependencies

I'm trying to design mediator micro-service which will have around 20-30 different http requests to an external vendor.

My general high level thoughs are on creating a BaseService class which will implement the Template Method pattern where each inherited class will be responsible on specific call, with its own request/response dtos, and have the ability to implement its own ParseResponse

I came to this as all requests to that vendor include a token, logging, retry mechanism and maybe more while the uniqueness of each service is its url, method (post,get,put), and maybe more.

Some requests will need some validation (calling to another in-house micro-service) before going to vendor.
I'm planning to have that covered with different interfaces like IValidationService.

My problem with this approach is that I'll have to have a Manager class to orchestrate flows, and since some flows include about 15 calls to that vendor I'll end up the Manager class to have 15 dependencies just for the vendor services classes alone which is bad practice.

I'm thinking if there is a better approach to my chosen above, or is there a way to prevent from ending my Manager class having so many dependencies.

Comment: What would be your approach if you didn't know any software patterns?

Comment: It's actually my intuition/experience that led me to make those decisions which later "had a name".

Comment: Alright.  What do you consider "bad practice" for the number of dependencies your class can have?  Is it 7?  3?  More than one? Intuitively, I feel like you need to call this a "service."  You are then free to use as many classes and methods as you need.  If what you need instead is actually *decoupling,* there are software patterns like the Command Pattern (as an example) that can provide that.

Comment: It is unclear to my why you're talking about a _mediator_ micro-service and your subsequent concern is "[needing] to have 15 dependencies" which is _precisely_ the kind of problem that the mediator pattern helps you solve. Did you exclude the mediator pattern as a valid approach here; or did you coincidentally use "mediator" without referring to the pattern itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that the Template pattern might be a good fit. I tend to find it overly abstract when trying to debug code that uses that pattern (even code I wrote within the last week).

My preference when building a service API is to use the Command pattern. Each call to the service's public API calls a specific command object under the hood. Those commands could be polymorphic so the constructors all look the same, and they all use the same logging and retry mechanisms.

It could look something like this (Ruby):

```rb
class MyServiceApi
  def api_feature_1
    MyCommand1.new(token).execute
  end

  def api_feature_2
    MyCommand2.new(token).execute
  end

  # ...
end

class Command
  # define a getter for the token
  attr_reader :token

  def initialize(token)
    # store the token in an instance variable
    @token = token
  end

  def vendor_api
    # store the vendor_api object in an instance variable
    # this syntax functions as both an initializer (on the 
    # first call) and a getter on subsequent calls

    @vendor_api ||= VendorApi.new(token)
  end

  def log(something_to_log)
    # call the universal logging mechanism
  end

  def retry(&block)
    # this would use some universal logic to determine
    # when to retry the block that was passed in
  end
end

class MyCommand1 < Command
  def execute
    result = {}

    retry do
      vendor_api.do_vendory_thing_1
      vendor_api.do_vendory_thing_2
      # ...
      result = vendor_api.do_vendory_thing_n
    end

    log(result)
    parse_response(result)
  end
end

class MyCommand2 < Command
  def execute
    result = {}

    retry do
      vendor_api.do_vendory_thing_10
      vendor_api.do_vendory_thing_11
      # ...
      result = vendor_api.do_vendory_thing_n
    end

    log(result)
    parse_response(result)
  end
end
```

Looking at this simple sample code, I can see where you might want to use the Template pattern. I would not go there until I had several concrete examples and felt certain that no other use cases exist. Why? Because undoing the Template pattern is painful enough that people usually just start adding all kinds of conditional logic in their template to "adjust" what it does in their specific use case. And, as we all know, conditional logic is the root of all complexity.

One other thing to consider: If your service will be making synchronous HTTP calls to the vendor service, you may want to implement a circuit breaker so that you don't slam their service when the HTTP connection is down, or when you get rate limited.